# ZeroMQ Pub Sending Empty String

Tags: c++, zeromq, memcpy

I've got a simple C++ PUB and python SUB set up, with intent to have C++ side built as a simple DLL eventually. I've had some prior experience with a similar set up with python on both sides, and no issues. I am, however a total C++ noob.

My C++ code:

```
#define ZMQ_EXPORT

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "zmq.hpp"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t publisher(context, ZMQ_PUB);
    publisher.bind("tcp://*:6666");

    zmq::message_t message(5);
    memcpy(message.data(), "Hello", 5);

    while(true) {
        Sleep(500);
        publisher.send(message);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Result from python SUB script on recv_multipart():

> ['']

I am confident it is otherwise working, though I think there's a flaw with how I am doing the memcpy.

Comment: could you post the python examples that worked for you? I believe you're missing a small zmq piece.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm thinking your missing the whole 'subscription' part of pub/sub

You need to give the PUB message some sort of message filter. This also means that your SUB needs to do the [`setsockopt`](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1%3azmq-setsockopt) to be able to receive messages.

You're given example shows that you in fact do not have a message filter for your PUB message (or rather your "Hello" IS your message filter and the data message is infact an empty string).

Comment: You're right. I convinced myself it's the C++ code, but I would normally be using send_multipart([...]) in python. Thanks.

Comment: no problem :) sometimes mixing between different bindings can get to the point where they simple things are what causes all of the trouble